# Git or SVN for solo developer with Android Studio on Windows?

Tags: android, git, svn, version-control

I've looked at the various previous posts on this provocative topic :) I'm not looking for a religious argument here but specific problems/advantages for either system. I have limited previous experience with both.

- performance on Windows?
- ability to host on my desktop but take with me on a laptop
- ease of use as solo developer
- but later ability to merge in another developer
- anything else I should be thinking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git.

See a detailed comparison here https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnComparison

If you want a free private repository there is bitbucket

Comment: Great link - I'm surprised it didn't pop when I was googling. I'll check out bitbucket too.

Comment: @Opus1217 some of the information provided in the linked article is not true. For example, the section "Smaller Space Requirements" is false.

Answer (score 1):

For solo developing i always use [GitHub](https://github.com/).
This is only my personal opinion, but i found him very useful:

- Free cloud (for public repositories)
- Windows client very easy to configure (and good performance)
- You can view (and clone) your projects through browser everywhere
- Paid version very cheap (7$ for 5 private repositories)